# raw input mode on stdin in Cygwin/Mintty

Tags: cygwin, stdin, mintty

I want to get my stdin into raw input mode in Cygwin/Mintty. How do I do that? Right now, it is line-buffered. With raw input mode, I mean that `read` returns on every single entered character.

I would prefer to do that without any further dependencies. I.e. I guess this probably can be done by linking against some libs from Cygwin, however, if it is possible, I'd like to avoid that.

Some search results: [libuv issue](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/issues/358), [libuv win/tty.c](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/master/src/win/tty.c), [Cygwin tty.cc](https://github.com/scottt/cygwin-vmci-sockets/blob/master/winsup/cygwin/tty.cc), [Cygwin fhandler_tty.cc](https://github.com/openunix/cygwin/blob/master/winsup/cygwin/fhandler_tty.cc), [Cygwin post (non-blocking stdin)](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-05/msg00298.html), [Mintty issue](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=56), [Msysgit issue](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=29)

I tried via `SetConsoleMode`, but that only works for the Windows console, not for Mintty. I.e. this code:

```
    // Setting terminal to raw mode...
    HANDLE hStdin;
    DWORD mode;
    //hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    hStdin = (HANDLE) _get_osfhandle(STDIN_FILENO);

    if (GetFileType(hStdin) == FILE_TYPE_CHAR) {
        cout << "stdin is file type char" << endl;
        GetConsoleMode(hStdin, &mode);
        if (
            !SetConsoleMode(
                hStdin,
                mode & ~(ENABLE_LINE_INPUT|ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT))
        ) {
            cerr << "Cannot set stdin to raw mode" << endl;
            // ignore...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `system( "stty -raw" );` work?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @trudyscousin its not a new question, its a proposal for a solution to his question.